# Tkinter: Place one or more label, each one with different fonts

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python and tkinter.
I need to place one or more label, each one with different fonts in this code.
The code is running in my MAC.
I've tried to insert more labels but the result doesn't appear on the screen, only the one of the first label.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("Title")
root.geometry('800x600')

MyText="""Line 1
Line 2"""

def resize_image(event):
    new_width = event.width
    new_height = event.height
    image = copy_of_image.resize((new_width, new_height))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label.config(image = photo)
    label.image = photo #avoid garbage collection

image = Image.open('pptfileteado.gif')
copy_of_image = image.copy()
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
#label = ttk.Label(root, image = photo)
label = ttk.Label(root, 
                  compound=CENTER, 
                  text=MyText, 
                  foreground='white', 
                  justify='center',
                  font = "Ayres 70", 
                  image = photo)

label.bind('<Configure>', resize_image)
label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand = YES, side="right")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have created just one label...what did you expect?

Comment: What does "in my MAC" mean? Do you mean it's running on a Macintosh? If so, it's "Mac", not "MAC".

Comment: You're right. It's Mac, Macintosh.

Comment: for each widget you create you will need to call `label.pack()` on it.  (or `.grid()` or `.place()`) Otherwise they are not put into the actual GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified where you want to put your label. To do this, you can use `.grid()`, `.pack()` or `.place()`. `.grid()` will allow you to place a specific place with `row` and `column`, `.pack()` will place the label at the next available place in the window. For example:

```
label = ttk.Label(root, text="Example")
label.pack()
```

This would pack the `label` into the next available space in the code.

Hope I could help :)